# Determine data type in linq query

Tags: c#, linq, types

I have this LINQ query :

```
double[] _x = CV.trainingDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                .Where(x => x.Field<int>("rk") == i)
                .Select(x => x.Field<double>("years"))
                .ToArray();
```

my problem is that I don't know for sure what is the data type of the values in "rk" and "years" column, and it raises an exception.
would like to know how can I re-write this query to be more flexible
thanks a lot.

Comment: what do you mean by flexible?

Comment: Does `Field<object>` work for you?

Comment: Debug the code and see which type the columns are in the DataTable?

Comment: Or check the data types from the conversion chart for your specific database platform.

Comment: "it raises an exception" - so how about sharing what the Exception is, and where it points to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say flexible but i say that would be more prone to errors. The [`Field`-extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301394(v=vs.110).aspx) is type-safe. It will enable you to use it with the correct types instead of fiddling around with `System.Object`(which the `DataRow` actually stores). But you have to know what type it is.

For the reason above i won't show you how to circumvent it(f.e. with using `ToString` and then parsing to your desired type). You should know what type it is.

You can detect the [types of the `DataColumn`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datatype(v=vs.110).aspx) via the table's `Columns`:

```
Type theTypeOfTheColumnRK = CV.trainingDataTable.Columns["rk"].DataType;
Type theTypeOfTheColumnYears = CV.trainingDataTable.Columns["years"].DataType;
```

You could execute these statements for example in the debugger to determine the types.